# jQGrid dynamic URI on 'formatoptions' of formatter actions

Tags: jqgrid, formatter

Actually I have implemented a REST solution to POST, PUT and DELETE data from the NavGrid on jQGrid.

Now in the actions buttons for each row, I try to do the same, but i don't know how generate a dynamic url on default formatter actions.

I try with this:

```
colModel : [
          {name:'actions', index:'', width:80, fixed:true, sortable:false, resize:false,
              formatter:'actions', 
              formatoptions:{ 
                  url: function(cellValue, rowId, rowData){
                      return restPutURL + '/' + rowId ;
                  },
                  mtype: 'PUT',
                  keys:true,
                  delOptions:{
                      url: restDelURL,
                      recreateForm: true, 
                      beforeShowForm:beforeDeleteCallback,
                      onclickSubmit :function(params, postdata) {
                        params.url += '/' + postdata;
                      }
                  }
              }
          },
          { ...my cols.. }
       ]
```

Delete action is ok, but edit doesn't work. When a row is saved jQGrid send function as part of the URI:

```
system/function%20(cellValue,%20rowId,%20rowData)%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(cellValue);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20/system/function%20(cellValue,%20rowId,%20rowData)%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20
```

How I can create a dynamic URI? or, how I can add the id of the edited row to the URI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use current version of jqGrid you can use `beforeSaveRow` callback to make some actions, like modification of URL, before the row will be saved. Unfortunately `formatter: "actions"` don't allow you to set `beforeSaveRow` callback, but you can still use `$.jgrid.inlineEdit` to do this. The corresponding code could be something like

```js
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.inlineEdit, {
    beforeSaveRow: function (option, rowId) {
        option.url = restPutURL + '/' + rowId;
    }
});
```

or

```js
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.inlineEdit, {
    beforeSaveRow: function (option, rowId) {
        option.url = this.p.editurl + '/' + rowId;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Oleg..can you please help me on this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094046/how-to-bind-null-value-to-jqgrid-that-contains-all-rows-in-editable-format

Comment: @oleg.I need your sugesstion above..if you are not busy..i was not able to to it since long time..