# How to bind null value to jqgrid that contains all rows in Editable format

Tags: jqgrid, html-select

I am using jqgrid in my asp.net application. I am making all the grid rows in editable fomat in the LoadComplete trigger of the jqgrid as follows:

```
 ids = $("#grid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                    var l = ids.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i <= l; i++) {
                        $("#grid").jqGrid('editRow', ids[i], true);
}
```

In two of the columns , i have dropdown lists . Here, the based on the external dropdown change, some rows get addded to the jqgrid.

When added, they contain the Null values initially.

So, inorder to show null values in grid. I am adding an list item , to display them.

The problem is here , i should not allow users to again select null values.

So, i need that option in the dropdown list only once that is before a selection is made.

later, it should not be visible or selectable..

Please help on this..

**Updated:**

Initially the grid contains no rows..

On the dropdown change , the grid gets refreshed and new rows are added based on dropdown selection.

**grid data**

```
for example:     
  col1  col2  col3  col4

  Item1 Null  null  null
  Item2 Null  Null  Null
```

similarly like this:

Here, Col1 is not editable rest of them are editable.

Col2 and Col4 are dropdowns

I am loading select options into dropdown by using

```
 editoptions: {
                    value: { " ": " ", "option1": "option1", "option2": "option2", "option2": "option2", "option3": "option3" },
```

Here, my problem is that .. the user should not be able to select that null option .

I have included it for the intial data binding.
IF i am not including that null option("")
then the dropdowns are showing with option 1 as default but the user has not yet selected any option.

Comment: It's not clear from the description how dropdown are defined (`editoptions.value` for example). Why new added rows contains NULL? Do you used `defaultValue` property? An example with some test data could clear many additional questions.

Comment: @Thanks Oleg..For your respone..Please see my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand correct your problem. If you just need to remove `null` or `""` entry from drop-down you can do this by using `dataInit` (the property of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions)). The corresponding code could be about the following

```
dataInit: function (elem) {
    $(elem).find("option[value=\"\"]").remove();
}
```

Probably other implementation could be better for you. For example you can unselect any option if the current selected option is `""`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857806/315935) for details. In any way I think that you should use `dataInit` to makes some corrections.